# Unable to Get Real Type from Global Declaration in TypeScript Project References

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, tsconfig, project-reference

I have created a [demo repository](https://github.com/kaokei/typescript-project-references) to illustrate my issue. The repository contains two projects: `electron` and `src`, and I am using TypeScript project references.

I have defined the type `API_TYPE` in the `src/global.d.ts` file by importing it from the `electron/src/index.ts` file. However, Visual Studio Code (VSCode) is unable to correctly infer the real type of `API_TYPE` from `src/global.d.ts`. When I open the `src/main.ts` file in VSCode, I see a tooltip indicating that the type is not recognized.
[image]

I suspect the issue might be related to the `references` field in the `tsconfig.json` file. If I remove the `references` field, everything works fine. However, I cannot remove the `references` field because the `electron` and `src` projects need to be separate.

Here is the relevant code from `src/global.d.ts`:

```
import type { API_TYPE } from "../electron/src/index";

declare global {
  interface Window {
    electronAPI: PRELOAD_API_TYPE<API_TYPE>;
  }
}

export {};
```

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!

---

**Edit at 05-30**

I have reuploaded the demo repository. The previous demo was functioning correctly and could not reproduce my issue.

Furthermore, I have identified that the problem is caused by the Vue component. Removing the Vue component `src/components/HelloWorld.vue` allows for correct inference of the type of window.electronAPI.

---

**Edit at 05-31**

I have re-created an [online demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-du4r3v?file=src%2Fmain.ts&terminal=dev), but to my surprise, it actually works properly. However, when I download this project to my local machine and open it using the local VSCode editor, the type inference results are not displayed correctly. Specifically, when I hover over the `api` and `API_TYPE` variables in the `src/main.ts` file, the local VSCode does not show their corresponding types.

The screenshot below shows an online demo displaying the correct types.
[image]

The screenshot below illustrates the issue where the local VSCode editor fails to display the correct types.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a solution. Just need to enable the takeover mode of Volar and it should work correctly.

https://cn.vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#volar-takeover-mode